# Why p-wave superconductors are rare in nature?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, topological-insulators

I have the basic question that why so many superconducting materials are s-wave and d-wave pairing, but the p-wave superconductors are so rare in nature?  An equivalent question may be that why topological materials are so rare in nature, but the answer to the this question may be more complicated then my first question.